# lineas en pdf usando iText y C#

Tags: mysql, c#, itext, border

Uso iText con c# y tambien mysql a la hora de pasarlo a pdf saca lineas horizontales y verticales o sea en cuadros todo el texto... quisiera saber como quitarlo, todo lo que he visto en internet, sacan las tablas con cuadros... Gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te refieres a sacar los bordes de la tabla?

Comment: Asi es, quitarlos bordes, ya probé con todo... incluso agregar: .SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER). y no hace nada... lo agregue a la tabla o a cada linea de celda y tampoco...

Comment: Agrega el codigo de la tabla Itext las propiedades son ``cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;``  o  ``table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;``